# AWS Aurora serverless mysql, Cognito, Lambda, API gateway, CloudFormation starter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework, aws-aurora-serverless

I was hoping to find a clear guide or an example on how to setup a serverless backend with the following technologies:

- Serverless framework
- AWS Aurora Serverless (mysql or postgres)
- AWS Cognito
- AWS Lambda
- AWS API Gateway
- CloudFormation scripts for (creating the above resources)
- Node/Express.js

Unfortunately, so far most of the resources I have come across have been either simplistic or ambiguous. And the ones that were not were focused on using just DyanmoDB. I was hoping to find a starter project with all the above technologies (especially Aurora serverless and NOT DynamoDB). Please share if you know.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/serverless/serverless and see https://github.com/serverless/examples for examples

Comment: That's a good request! :)

Answer (score 2):

I have recently been working on something like this and it covers some of the technologies that you're talking about, specifically:

- Serverless
- Api Gateway
- Serverless Aurora (Postgres)
- AWS Lambda
- Cloudformation (VPC)

You could potentially use this serverless.yml as a starting point: https://github.com/Compulsed/blog/blob/master/backend/serverless.yml

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you using this for production? I want to build a property listing app with this setup. Butm I wonder if this is a scalable solution. I wanted to use Aurora serverless mysql/postgres. I am reading conflicting information about its pricing and cold start delays.

Comment: It is currently being used in production but not for anything serious. The pausing (cold starts?) can be completely turned off and the Serverless Aurora should be able to scale up.

As an FYI I recently pulled out the Aurora part into a starter project if that is something you are more interested in (it is based on the backend that I had built out for the blog). https://github.com/Compulsed/serverless-aurora-graphql-starter